Probability of $\frac{a}{b}$ in interval in $[1,3]$
If $a,b$ is uniform in $[0,1]$, then what is the probability that $\frac{a}{b}$ is in $[1,3]$. Both variables are independent.
I found the probability being $\frac{1}{3}$ by double integrating whilst bounding b as between $\frac{1}{3}a \le{b} \le a$. However, if I do the same integration but now bounding a as $b \le{a} \le 3b$, I get that the probability is 1. Shouldn't these two bounds yield the same answers?
What is the issue?

Without independence both are wrong.

Assume they are independent.

Some relevance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240643/two-numbers-are-chosen-at-random-over-the-interval-0-1

Plot values of $b$ on the $x$-axis and values of $a$ on the $y$-axis.  Then $(a,b)$ is a point in the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.  The set of points for which $a/b \in [1,3]$ corresponds to points in this square for which a line drawn through $(a,b)$ and the origin, has slope between $1$ and $3$ inclusive.
Since the line $y = x$ has slope $1$ and the line $y = 3x$ has slope $3$, it follows that the set of points $(a,b)$ corresponds to the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1/3,1)$.  This triangle has area $$\frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{3},$$ and since the square has area $1$, the desired probability is $1/3$.
The reason why your second approach doesn't work is because you did not take into account that $b \le a \le 3b$ also requires $a \le 1$.  So when $b > 1/3$, then $3b > 1$.  We can write the area integral as:
$$\int_{a=0}^1 \int_{b=a/3}^a \, db \, da,$$
which does not have any issues because for any $a \in [0,1]$, the interval $[a/3, a]$ lies entirely inside $[0,1]$.  But if we try to switch the order of integration, then
$$\int_{b=0}^1 \int_{a = b}^{3b} \, da \, db$$
is incorrect because as stated above, when $b > 1/3$, the upper limit $3b$ is greater than $1$.  You must either write
$$\int_{b=0}^1 \int_{a = b}^{\min(1,3b)} \, da \, db$$
or split up the integral into the cases $0 \le b \le 1/3$ and $1/3 < b \le 1$:
$$\int_{b=0}^{1/3} \int_{a=b}^{3b} \, da \, db + \int_{b=1/3}^1 \int_{a=b}^1 \, da \, db.$$

Thank you for the explanation!

Using the triangle to find the probability is so elementarily simple :") Why can't I ever find these simple things. I had a similar question this sem, but it had $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ instead of $\frac{a}{b}$. Any suggestions to solve it like this? (Here $a,b\in [-1,1]$)
